# Getting browser-sync to play nice with ember-cli and a localhost API server

Tags: node.js, api, ember.js, browser-sync

I've been trying to get [browser-sync](http://www.browsersync.io/) to play nice with [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/) via [ember-cli-browser-sync](https://github.com/dylanharrington/ember-cli-browser-sync) (installed via `"ember-cli-browser-sync": "git://github.com/dylanharrington/ember-cli-browser-sync.git"` in `package.json` as it isn't on the npm registery) with my localhost API server, but have been unable to get it to work.

Just doing

```
serverMiddleware: function(config) {
  config.options.liveReload = false;
  browserSync({
    injectChanges: true,
    reloadDelay:   10,
    notify:        false,
    open:          false,
    proxy: "localhost:4200"
  });
},
```

Works wonderfully for a local device, but fails at accessing my api at http://localhost:8000/api/1 from an external device (iPhone).

I tried to extend the proxy settings to include my local API via:

```
var url = require('url'),
    proxy = require('proxy-middleware');

serverMiddleware: function(config) {
  config.options.liveReload = false;

  var proxyOptions = url.parse('http://localhost:8000/api/1');

  browserSync({
    injectChanges: true,
    reloadDelay:   10,
    notify:        false,
    open:          false,
    proxy: {
      target: 'localhost:4200',
      middleware: [proxy(proxyOptions)]
    }
  });

});
```

Which basically serves the API to my external URL provided by BrowserSync.

So I tried to utilise `server`:

```
serverMiddleware: function(config) {
  config.options.liveReload = false;

  var proxyOptions = url.parse('http://localhost:8000/api/1');
  console.log(proxyOptions);
      // proxyOptions.route = '/api';

  browserSync({
    injectChanges: true,
    reloadDelay:   10,
    notify:        false,
    open:          false,
    port: 3000,
    server: {
      baseDir: "./",
      routes: {
        "/app": "app",
        "/assets": "dist/assets",
      },
      index: "app/index.html",
      middleware: function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.url);
        next();
      }
    }
  });
},
```

Which serves the correct index, and all the `asset` files, but causes an error with ember.

Does anyone have any experience doing this and which path I should try next? Is there a different NPM package I should try to use to proxy my API?

Answer (score 1):

I gave up trying to solve this myself and ended up just using [XIP](http://xip.io/), which might suit your needs.

Comment: Interesting, how does one expose an API under localhost:8000? do I need to alias the host and then use that on xip.io?

Comment: I've never tried to do something like `0.0.0.1:8000.10.0.0.1.xip.io`. Might work. If not you could set up a virtual host (something like pow, though I don't what you are using for your API).